# Relax NG and uniqueness of elements/attributes

Tags: xml, schema

is it possible to make a Relax NG element/attribute unique?

For example the attribute:

```
<rng:attribute name="test">
        <rng:ref name="options"/>
</rng:attribute>
```

references to:

```
<rng:define name="options">
    <rng:choice>
        <rng:value>t1</rng:value>
        <rng:value>t2</rng:value>
        <rng:value>t3</rng:value>
    </rng:choice>
</rng:define>
```

Now i have to validate a xml, which shouldn't use one of the "options" twice. In other words: in the xml there shouldn't occure "t1" twice...

I've read something about schematron. But is there another possibility?

Answer (score 2):

No, uniqueness constraints and referential integrity constraints are not supported by Relax NG.  As James Clark says in [a paper on the design of Relax NG](http://www.thaiopensource.com/relaxng/design.html#section:16):

> The RELAX NG TC spent a considerable amount of time considering what support RELAX NG should provide for enforcing identity (uniqueness and cross-reference) constraints. In the end, the conclusion was that identity constraints were better separated out into a separate specification. Accordingly, RELAX NG itself provides no support for identity constraints.

For compatibility with XML DTDs, RelaxNG does support the checking of ID/IDREF constraints.  But this is one of the areas where it is easiest to run into inconsistency between processors and for new users to be confused.

Your options include

- checking the uniqueness of the values at the application level
- using another schema language (Schematron, DTDs, XSD) to formulate and enforce this constraint (of these, Schematron is probably easiest to use in practice as a way to supplement RelaxNG on specific points but leave most of the work to RelaxNG)
- rejiggering the XML so that the distinction among t1, t2, and t3 is expressed in the element names, and the content model can enforce their uniqueness; this is not necessarily possible

Answer (score 0):

Your schema fragments are okay as-is.

The schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<rng:element xmlns:rng="http://relaxng.org/ns/structure/1.0" name="doc">
  <rng:attribute name="test">
    <rng:choice>
      <rng:value>t1</rng:value>
      <rng:value>t2</rng:value>
      <rng:value>t3</rng:value>
    </rng:choice>
  </rng:attribute>
</rng:element>
```

permits the attribute test to have the value of either "t1", "t2" or "t3". If it contains anything else a RELAX NG validator will emit a validation error message. For example in that case [jing](http://code.google.com/p/jing-trang/) reports

```
"[Jing] value of attribute "test" is invalid; must be equal to "t1", "t2" or "t3"
```

.